# Execution failing with go error for acceptance tests

Tags: go, acceptance-testing, ginkgo

I am trying to execute acceptance testing (AATs), But when eveni try to use ginkgo command or make aat, it fails with below go error :

```
lisha@admin-bld-box:$ ginkgo
Failed to compile topology-middleware:

go: unknown flag -i cannot be used with -c
usage: go test [build/test flags] [packages] [build/test flags & test binary flags]
Run 'go help test' and 'go help testflag' for details.

Ginkgo ran 1 suite in 36.754007ms
Test Suite Failed
lisha@admin-bld-box:$ ^C
```

in makefile my ginko commnads are specified as below

```
GINKGO_SKIP  ?= SLOW
GINKGO_FLAGS ?= --progress --trace --v --slowSpecThreshold=15 --focus="$(GINKGO_FOCUS)" --skip="$(GINKGO_SKIP)"
```

kindly help me find the root cause

I have tried executing it via go test -v ./ which works, however i want to know the root cause for this line "go: unknown flag -i cannot be used with -c" in the error

Answer (score 2):

The -i flag was used in older versions of Go to specify that the go install command should install the dependencies of the specified packages. However, in Go 1.17 and later, the -i flag has been removed.